# How to check a directory for multiple files being extracted

Tags: powershell

I have a list of 3 files that are in a zip file. As an example, they are named `file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt`.

I then have a process that runs in the background that will automatically extract them into a folder that already contains other files.

I'd like to run a script that starts that process (I can do that), and then waits for those three files to be present in the directory before continuing operations. I've tried different combinations of `do` and `while` loops, but every time the loop results to `true` before the files are actually present. And if the tag wasn't enough of a hint, this is a PowerShell script.

Here is what I've got currently, though it is automatically going to the break:

```
do {
   $result = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$path\*" -Recurse -Include $emvfiles, $pefiles -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Test-Path) -notcontains $false
   if ($result) {
      Write-Host "All files extracted. Continuing..."
      break
   }
} while ($true)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a "process that runs in the background that will automatically extract them" ? Why not have the main code do that sequentially ?

Comment: That process already exists. I have no control over it. It's used to extract the files. I'm looking for a way to determine if the files in the archive have been extracted.

Comment: Add the code you currently have and is not working to your question please

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that the extraction process may create the filename and write to it for some time. `Test-Path` will see the filename and return `$true` while the extract process is still writing the file. The probability of this happening increases as the file sizes get larger.

Comment: The files are only about 5 KB each. They're just XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the condition in the `do-while` loop is always evaluating to `true` because the `Test-Path` cmdlet returns a boolean value, and the `-notcontains` operator is not used correctly. So to solve it use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) to get the files in the directory and filter for the specific file names you want. then check if the count of the extracted files is equal to 3, indicating that all three files are present. If so, break out of the loop.

```
do {
     $extractedFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "file1.txt" -or $_.Name -eq "file2.txt" -or $_.Name -eq "file3.txt"}
    if ($extractedFiles.Count -eq 3) {
        Write-Host "Tous les fichiers ont été extraits. Continuation..."
        break
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} while ($true)
```

`Start-Sleep -Seconds 1`: wait for 1 second and then check again.

Comment: I added to the question that there will be other files in the directory, so just checking the count won't work.

Comment: You said "I have a list of 3 files that are in a zip file. Call them"?

Comment: Fixed now you can check, I've added test for those three files file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt

Comment: It did. I made 1 small change: I already had the names of the files in a variable, so I changed to `Where-Object { $_.Name -in $files }`. Thanks